# Browser button is not clicking in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing selenium webdriver. i have some issue.If i click on Browse button then should display popup.so my application not clicking and not opening Browser.

```
try{

    WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form[1]/p[2]/input"));

    fileInput.sendKeys("C:\\Documents and Settings\\mahesh\\Desktop\\button then display msg.png");

    System.out.println("valid");

    }

catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {

    System.err.println("invalid");

    }
```

I got one issue coming .

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form[1]/p[2]/input"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.06 seconds
```

this type of error coming .

so please any one guide me to over come this issue.

thanks
mahesh.k

Comment: Plz share your html code too so that one could help you more specifically

Comment: from my side I'd like to add that before you perform sendKeys() operation it better to clear the input field with .clear() method

Answer (score 0):

From the above error, i think it's unable to find the element on your webpage...do cross verify the Xpath expression written....

Moreover Before sending the keys(File path)....do perform the click over the Button which opens the Pop-up...and then Send the Keys...

Here is working C# code on http://www.freeimagehosting.net/upload.php

```
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.freeimagehosting.net/upload.php");

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement returnedValue = driver.FindElement(By.Name("attached"));
        returnedValue.Click();
        returnedValue.SendKeys("C:\\file.png");
```

the above code...looks for Browse button in the webpage and then performs a "**Click**" operation  for pop-up to Open and then sends the path of "**Image File**".

I hope this helps...All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is not finding the element. First you can verify what elements selenium webdriver is likely to find by using selenium IDE. Download selenium IDE plugin for firefox browser [here](http://seleniumhq.org/download/).
Another thing to look at is the xpath you have specified. Selenium does not recognize an xpath unless you start with "//" or "xpath=" so I would change your element search to

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form[1]/p[2]/input"));
```

If that does not work then use selenium IDE to verify the element's xpath before searching for it in Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

html/body/form[1]/p[2]/input -- Absolute XPath

This XPath will not work always. Use the "id" or "name" attribute given in the Input Tag.

Please Let me know Is my Funda Worked.